# BLE CoreBluetooth in Background, what I am authorized to do?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, background

I've designed a very simple wearable BLE device with one physical button. This device  has a UART Service and can notify a connected device when the value change (when the button is pressed).

My goal: The smartphone must be able to send an HTTP request in background every time the button is pressed. even when the app is not running.

For this need, I have to implement the iOS Bluetooth background process with CoreBluetooth. But before, i would like to know if CoreBluetooth can meet my need.

So my questions are:

- Is it technically possible to keep a long-term background connection between Smartphone and BLE device, even if the Smartphone reboot.
- Can I wake up or start my app in foreground (without notification) when the BLE device button is pressed.
- And if the previous statement is not possible, can I execute a very basic HTTP request in background when the user press the button ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 1. Yes; see the Core Bluetooth Programming guide on background processing and state restoration. 2. No. 3. Yes

Comment: Thank for your answer @Paulw11, Glade to see that the answer for the 3rd statement is "yes", i was not sure at all.